# MongoDB ssl via C# driver: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssl

I am trying to test authentication using X.509 self-signed certificate from C# client to MongoDB. I have **succeeded** in running *mongod* **in a console window** using ssl and connecting to it from another console window with *mongo* command:

`mongod --clusterAuthMode x509 --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile mongodb.pem --sslCAFile client.pem`

`mongo --ssl --sslCAFile mongodb.pem --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem`

Certificate files were generated by following [these instructions](http://demarcsek92.blogspot.dk/2014/05/mongodb-ssl-setup.html).

MongoDB driver requires pfx file that I generated by:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.pem -inkey client-cert.key -out client.pfx`

Actual code is below:

```
    private static void TryConnect()
    {
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\client.pfx", "test");

        var settings = new MongoClientSettings
        {
            Credentials = new[]
            {
                MongoCredential.CreateMongoX509Credential("subject= emailAddress=test@test.com,CN=127.0.0.1,OU=Test,O=Test,L=Cph,C=DK")
            },
            SslSettings = new SslSettings
            {
                ClientCertificates = new[] { cert },
            },
            UseSsl = true
        };

        settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("127.0.0.1");            

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("test");

        db.CreateCollection("test");           
    }
```

The last line throws an exception: *Unable to connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.*

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the CRL is valid.

The following link describes a misconfiguration in the HTTP URL causing this issue in another scenario (not related to mongodb)

http://www.coretekservices.com/2014/jun/26/certificate-services-did-not-start-sub-ca

You can get more information by validating the cert and examining the policy errors (note the warning)

**WARNING: DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!!! FIX THE CERT ISSUE INSTEAD**

```
 settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings
        {
            ClientCertificates = new[] { cert },
            ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                foreach (var item in chain.ChainElements)
                {
                    foreach (var elemStatus in item.ChainElementStatus)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( item.Certificate.Subject + "->" + elemStatus.StatusInformation);
                    }
                }

                return true; //NOT FOR PRODUCTION: this line will bypass certificate errors.
            }
       }
```

Comment: The link is dead, unfortunately. Can you describe how to fix this properly @nambi?

Answer (score 0):

[Nambi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726223/mongodb-ssl-via-c-sharp-driver-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-t/34735350#34735350) helped me to identify the issue. Self-signed root certificate wasn't trusted. The issue went away after *mongodb-cert.crt* was added to *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* under *Certificates (Local Computer)* snap-in.